# How to use D3-GraphViz in Javascript with an Angular template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, d3.js, graphviz

I'm trying to use `d3-graphviz` as described [here](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz-angular) in an angular template, such as [this one](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/paper-dashboard-angular). The demo on the `d3-graphviz` site instructs me to put the following code in the `index.html` file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@hpcc-js/wasm@0.3.11/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@3.0.5/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .renderDot('digraph  {a -> b}');

</script>
```

However, when I put this in the dashboard.component.html file (which is where I want the result to show), I get the following error in the console

```
ERROR TypeError: pe.select is not a function
at h.ngOnInit (383.js:1:105583)
at Ki (main.js:1:183802)
at qn (main.js:1:183633)
at ao (main.js:1:183353)
at Ha (main.js:1:210163)
at Gv (main.js:1:210461)
at Ha (main.js:1:210486)
at $v (main.js:1:217064)
at wv (main.js:1:210896)
at Ha (main.js:1:210907)
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. I can provide more information if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because by the time you run your script `d3` is not loaded yet.

Put `d3` scripts in `head` tag and then run the script like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .renderDot('digraph  {a -> b}');
});
```

This way the script will execute after all script links are loaded.